# why my code only print 'bbb' once,and it does not run wrong unexpectedly

Tags: python

```
class a:
    class __b__(object):
        print 'bbb'

b=a()
b.__b__()
b.__b__()
b.__b__()
a.__b__()
a.__b__()
a.__b__()
```

it print 'bbb' only once,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class __b__` statement executes exactly once (when the `class a` statement executes) and that's the only case in which you're `print`int anything.  The various instantiations are totally irrelevant (none of them has anything to do with the `print`ing).

Answer (score 4):

When python creates a class, it does so by executing the code within the class definition **exactly once**, therefore creating the class namespace, etc...

If you wanted it to run each time you called it, you need to put your code in the `__init__` method (which is the constructor).

```
class a:
    class b:
        def __init__(self):
            print 'bbb'

a.b()
a.b()
```

That will print `bbb` 2x.  Notice that you don't need an instance of `a()` to access `a.b` because `class b` is simply an attribute of `class a`.  Your really don't gain much by nesting classes in python.

Notice I did not use `__b__`, because python reserves words that start and end with double underscores.

Comment: Just a note; if you're using python 2.x, print is not a function, so adding the parentheses may give you weird results.

Answer (score 3):

You don't explain what you are trying to do, but I think what you mean is:

```
class a:
    def __b__(object):
        print 'bbb'
```

Comment: Why the down votes? This may very well be what the question is asking, how often do you even use subclasses in python?